# On an <Input> (like <TextInput>) onChange => How do I send this value to a different field?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have `<TextInput>` 1 and `<TextInput>` 2.

When I type "Foo" in 1, I want 2 to also == "Foo", like:

```xml
<TextInput
  label='From Here (Send val to below)'
  source='firstName'
  onChange={ val => sendThisValToTextInputBelow(val) }
/>

<TextInput
  label='To Here (Receive val from above)'
/>
```

Comment: can you please check the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Use state management, and reference the same state variable:

```
const [ value, setValue ] = useState('');

<TextInput
  label='From Here (Send val to below)'
  source='firstName'
  value={ value }
  onChange={ val => setValue(val) } />

<TextInput
  value={ value }
  label='To Here (Receive val from above)' />
```

Comment: In theory, I understand it. However, *where* do I set this const? Everywhere I try, I get an err: https://i.imgur.com/znfdISc.png

Comment: It should be declared in the component (where you have it second). You also need to import `useState` from React.... `import React, { useState } from 'react';`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by having a state variable. ANd then just use that state variable in both `TextInput`.

[**Stackblitz Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nfbjti?file=src%2FApp.js)

**Functional Component**

```
const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');

<TextInput
  label='From Here (Send val to below)'
  source='firstName'
  value={firstName} 
  onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)}
/>

<TextInput
  label='To Here (Receive val from above)'
  value={firstName}
/>
```

**Class Based Component**

```
constructor() {
   this.state = {
     firstName: ''
   }
}

<TextInput
  label='From Here (Send val to below)'
  source='firstName'
  value={firstName} 
  onChange={(e) => this.setState({ firstName: e.target.value })}
/>

<TextInput
  label='To Here (Receive val from above)'
  value={firstName}
/>
```

Comment: Where the heck do I even declare state in a <Filter>? I tried both inside and out: In `react-admin`, I can't seem to place it above or below. For example: https://i.imgur.com/znfdISc.png

Comment: @dylanh724 You should have basic knowledge of react first or just do google it's very basic question where to place `useState`. BTW I have created the stackblitz demo for you check it out https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nfbjti?file=src%2FApp.js